# svn checkout two paths in two directories

Tags: svn, svn-checkout

I need to checkout two paths in two directories. Here is what I've tried before:

```
svn co https://localhost:8443/svn/Code "d:\src" https://localhost:8443/svn/lines "d:\src\bin"
```

and similar commands, but only first path is checked out to the second directory with an  error svn: E125002: >D:/src< scheint keine URL zu sein
which means >D:/src< doesn't look like URL.

I've red the syntax [here](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svn/c/checkout/) but could not get it working.
Please provide me with working example.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <strike>As @namxee wrote (and `svn help co` remind) you **can't** use **more than two** parameters (SRC and TGT) in checkout</strike>Third command from VisualSVN Manual page will help (using three paramaters for multi-SRC checkout into common base) with correct syntax

`svn co https://localhost:8443/svn/Code https://localhost:8443/svn/lines d:\src`

which will give `Code` and `lines` subdirs as **two independent** Working Copies inside d:\src`

- Second problem is worse: even if with two separate commands you checkout two **sibling sources** (`/svn/Code` and `/svn/lines`) into parent|child Working Copies (`d:\src` + `d:\src\bin`), guaranteed to get Problems, when you'll try to commit (or successfully commit, I'm too lazy to predicts, where exactly your racks are) changes to Repo. Maybe you can describe **your bisiness task** for such exotic WC-placement

Comment: yes, second problem was really a problem :) I changed programm design and everything is fine now

Answer (score 1):

it seems to be impossible to chechout each directories.. by svn checkout command.

you have to command with only one line 
i recommed '&'

```
svn co https://localhost:8443/svn/Code "d:\src" & svn co https://localhost:8443/svn/lines "d:\src\bin"
```

it works well in linux OS

i hope it helps.

Comment: it works in windows as well. This is not a solution in my case, but really good to know. Thank you